# Client side validation with Jquery - MVC C# app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-component, client-side-validation

I am working on a very LEGACY ASP.NET MVC app using C# which is built from 2009. They don't have any client side validation at all. In other words, they don't use validation mechanism provided by the ASP.NET MVC framework as the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-side-validation

They use service, interface etc... to do validation. Not using data annotations, either. As a result, they don't have unit tests for model validator. All validation rules will be tested manually through server side only or the unit tests have strong dependency to `Resource.resx` or other services which I don't think they are unit tests.

Therefore, I have added a client side validation and server-side validation by using data anotations.

Unfortunately, my PR is declined because they said that they don't want to use or add jQuery to the current application.

The reason is that: "they want to build portable micro-frontends pointing at APIs rather than all encompassing large applications the current app. because of that jQuery Validate is at the complete opposite end of the scale from zero compromise. It can be done by HTML5 and plenty of other client side only JS libraries there are plenty of better compromises. The other end of the scale (our ideal) is the validation happens in an encapsulated web component that uses Angular Forms." (An answer from a Front end developer)

The problem is that we have not the plan to replace that legacy app yet and I don't see the reason why I cannot use Validation mechanism from Microsoft to do both client side and server side validation. My thought is that it is better to do validation in correct way, rather than let it be bad and will be replaced by web-component soon.

Based on the source code, I am not sure they are able to apply proper validation way in new technology because with the ASP.NET MVC app, I think they did not apply correctly or I don't think they understand the framework.

Any ideas why I should not use jQuery for MS's validation on a legacy app?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this would be better asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "*better to do validation in correct way*" - in *your* opinion.  That's the problem with terms like "better".  Sure it gives a better UX, but it's not *the* correct way.   In general:  Server-side validation is substantially more robust/less hackable etc, so if you're going to do one *or* the other, then it *has* to be server-side.

Comment: Why not doing client side validation? can you explain for me why it is not the correct way. Of course, I do always do both validation client and serverside. Thank you

Comment: I would say that there is a difference between using DataAnnotations and jquery validation.  DataAnnotations is front end agnostic  and you can use angular, custom javascript, react, jquery/jquery.validate, kendo, etc to do the validation.  The annotations just add additional data attributes that can be picked up and used by any front end.  Of course once you have that, it's trivially easy to drop in the 3 libraries (jquery, jquery.validate, jquery.unobstrusive) and take the easy win.  Even with no client-side, you get well tested server-side validation, so why not?

Comment: @RobertMcKee you are right. I just dont know why I cannot use Jquery for the client-side validation. As you can see, I am using DataAnnotations as it suits for my problem and it will provide both Client-side validation and server side validation. But I need Jquery to do client side validation. I agree that I can easily find another javascript lib to do client side validation but I see no reasons why I cannot use DataAnnotations. I dont see any reason using Jquery in our app will affect the performance. Thank you

Comment: @freedomn-m well you are right about the word "better" but if you have chance to look at our codes then you can understand why I said it is better. A good example is that you never see we use ModelSteate to do the validation. All validations rules is performed through some services and many duplicated codes with strong dependencies on the external resources.